# Chromium incognito default new window, click email link, terminal

Tags: xubuntu, chromium

I'm an OSX user that is experimenting and learning Linux for the last 7 month. I have a VMWare setup with Xubuntu and I have found myself not going back to OSX. Now I'm trying to learn a bit more about the ecosystem and how to set things that accommodate my needs. That said, this is more of a learning question than a fix.
I have Chromium install in my system. I went to `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.deskto` and copy that file into `/home/user/.local/share/applications` and change the setting `Exec=Chromium-browser --incognito`. Well that works if I fire the browser from `Synapse` or if I have an icon in the Panel. However, in the terminal, I need to pass the flag `--incognito` regardless. Also, if I use the menu inside Chromium itself and click new window, doesn't open in incognito. It is strange to me. Looks like different way to fire the application is pointing to a different executable in the system.
Does Lunix has the application waiting in different locations, or......
might be that inside the `chromium-browser.deskto` their configurations that can be done to manipulate this behavior?